# MATLAB: Need to make a 4D plot (3D + Colour/Color)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, colors, 3d

I need to make a 3D surface where colour will represent the fourth variable. I know "surf" is SIMILAR to what I need, but that's not quite it. Basically, I have the following variables:

t = [1:m]

y = [1:n]

a = [1:o]

These should be the three Cartesian corodinate axes.

I also have a variable S that is of dimensions m x n x o, and is basically the amplitude, a function of the previous three variables (i.e. S = f(t,y,a)). I want this to be represented by colour.

So to summarize, I need a graph of the form (t,y,a,S), where the first three variables are vectors of unequal sizes and the final variable is a multidimensional array whose dimensions are determined by the first three.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you end up doing? yuk solve your problem? Don't forget to select an answer :)

Answer (score 10):

SCATTER3 requires `x`, `y` and `z` and other grouping arguments to be equally-sized Nx1 vectors for a single series or NxM matrices for M series.

You have full space 3D data. To make equally-sized coordinate vectors use [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) (or [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html)) function:

```
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(t, y, a);
```

Then you can use SCATTER3:

```
scatter3( X(:), Y(:), Z(:), [], S(:) )
```

The problem is since it's full space data scatter3 will not be helpful specially if you have a lot of points.

You can probably filter your S variable (something like `idx  = S > 0`), then you can plot filtered data.

If you really need to visualize all the data, look at [Volume visualization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f5-8666.html) in MATLAB documentation. I can recommend [SLICE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/slice.html) function, for example.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of full 3D space scatter plot for small vectors (`m`, `n`, `o` equal to 5) with `S = rand([m,n,o]); scatter3( X(:), Y(:), Z(:), [], S(:), 'filled' )`

[image: scatter example]

**EDIT 2**

From your comments to the other answer I found that you have 32x76050x4 matrix. You can actually plot 2D slice one at a time. you can do it in 2D with IMAGESC function, or in 3D with SLICE function.

Try:

```
imagesc(S(:,:,k))
```

where `k` is a number from 1 to 4 for the 3rd dimension.

Or try

```
slice(S, [], [], 1:size(S,3))
shading flat
```

[image: slice example]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!  I will update you when I get the results! =D

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what that looks like, if possible?  I'm curious.  Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot of what? scatter plot? Remember it's full space, so it will not make much sense unless you filter the data. I can show it for small vectors.

Comment: I've always been a big fan of [ISOSURFACE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isosurface.html) for 4-D visualization. A few transparent isosurfaces can make a very pretty plot. ;)

Comment: @gnovice: Yea, it could be cool. I didn't know. The problem in this case is only 4 levels in 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this user-created plotting routine](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9519-color-coded-3d-scatterplot) can help.

Screnshot from the linked page:
[image: Screnshot from the linked page]

Comment: very nice script! much easier to load as compared to the output of scatter3 function.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used scatter3 for coloring/sizing pixels in 3d space.  I believe the signature is:

```
scatter3(x,y,z, size, color)
```

The size and color can be scalar or vector of length equal to the coordinates.  I usually use either the color or the size to reflect the fourth attribute, depending on what I'm showing.  I don't have Matlab on this machine, so forgive me if my memory isn't completely accurate on the usage.  "help scatter3" should describe it much better.

Comment: Thanks, I was also suggested this on the MATLAB forums.  I'll look into it.

However, in my case, what would I do with the size variable?  That one I'm not concerned about, but I am interested in the other four.

Comment: I have a set of time-domain signals that are separated in space, and I have taken the continuous-wavelet transform of them to get a scalogram. Thus, I have three variables as the axes: time (t), space (x), and scales/frequency (a), as well as the actual scalogram itself--or rather, a set of scalograms for each of the different spatially separated signals.

time is of length 76050
scales is of length 32
space is of length 4

Thus, the set of scalograms is a multidimensional array of length 32x76050x4, with the actual values inside representing the amplitude.

It's pretty confusing.

Comment: I just thought of an idea. What if I scaled the variables appropriately so that their sizes can fit into a function like surf or scatter3D? So currently, the variables are like 32x76050x4. Using linspace or something along those lines, I should be able to make thse guys line up.

Let me give this a try.