# matlab slice without interpolation

Tags: matlab, visualization, slice

I'm trying to visualize some 4-D data using matlab's slice tool. But because the array is 4x4x4, i would like to visualize it by slicing at all levels.

I use the following code to generate a plot:

```
data=round(rand(4,4,4));
h=slice(data,1:4,1:4,1:4);
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.3,'EdgeAlpha',1)
colormap gray
```

But the plot ends up representing a 3x3x3 array.

So it looks like matlab is interpolating some values. I've searched around to no avail -- how can i visualize the 4D data without interpolation (i.e., so each value in the array is represented by a cell in the figure)?

Comment: What do you mean by 4D data? `rand(4,4,4)` is 3D.

Comment: @Jigg The value would probably be considered the 4th dimension in this case.

Comment: Yeah, like a 3D surface represented by a 2D matrix.

Comment: There are 4 slices.  Look at the number of faces, not the number of cubes.

Comment: @chappjc I understand that there are four faces, but how can i generate a plot in which each voxel / cell represents an individual value in the data array?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960456/matlab-need-to-make-a-4d-plot-3d-colour-color