# 3D Scatter Plot for matrixes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, scatter-plot

How do i Scatter plot the following in 3 dimension?

```
X = [48 x 48 matrix];
Y = [48 x 48 matrix];
Z = [48 x 48 matrix];
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html

Comment: Not sure if it works for matrices or just for rows. But i thought the same as timgeb. If it doesn't work for matrices just loop over one dimension.

Comment: `scatter3(X(:),Y(:),Z(:))` ?

Comment: The suggestion by @LuisMendo works

Comment: And just in case you end up in this situation next: [Need to make a 4D plot (3D + Colour)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960456/matlab-need-to-make-a-4d-plot-3d-colour-color)